# PHP & MYSQL: checking whether certain DB exists in the server, from a php code executing mysql command

Tags: php, mysql

I want my php code to check whether a certain DB exists, by means of running some sql query andd parsing the result.

What would be a nice way to do it?

Thanks

Gidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run [SHOW DATABASES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-databases.html) and loop over the results with PHP to check for the existence.

If it were only one database, you could also add a condition to the SQL query directly and simply check if it returned a result or not with PHP. This would avoid the loop.

Comment: what do you mean by condition? I am looking for one certain db

Comment: Yeah, just one database add the `LIKE` condition. See **middaparka's** example or the docs.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple solution, you could just use:

```
SHOW DATABASES LIKE <YOUR DB NAME>;
```

See the [SHOW DATABASES Syntax manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-databases.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could connect to your server, and issue a [**`show databases`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-databases.html) statement.

It'll get you a list of all database **that you can access**, on your server.

I suppose you could also connect to your server, and, then, call [`mysql_select_db()`][2] or [`mysqli::select_db()`][3], to try connecting to your specific database.

If it doesn't exist, that function will most likely fail -- and return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it in code, you could do

```
mysql_connect('host','user','pass');
$dbExists=mysql_select_db('db_name');
```

Might be quicker too.